# How to calculate the mean of those columns in a data frame with the same column name

Tags: r

I have a data frame consisting of 10299 observations of 66 variables. Some of these variables share a common column name, and I would like to calculate the mean of those variables for each observation.

Having the following matrix, with column names `c(A, B, C, B, A ,C)`:

```
A B C B A C                             
1 2 3 4 5 6         
3 5 6 7 4 3                             
3 3 3 3 5 5                             
2 2 2 2 2 2
```

I would like to get:

```
A   B   C    
3   3   4.5
3.5 6   4.5
4   3   4
2   2   2
```

I tried for loops, the command `aggregate()` but I don't get the desired result.

Sorry if the question seems too basic, I have checked google for possible solutions but I didn't find any.

Comment: maybe transpose and then aggregate by group (where groups are A, B, C)?

Comment: @JohnPaul: only row.names must be unique..

Comment: [d.b's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46202066/4891738) using `split.default` is the best. Relevant: [What is the algorithm behind R core's `split` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52158589/4891738)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution.

First let's define an exemplary data.frame (the same as in your example).

```
df <- as.data.frame(
    matrix(c(1,3,3,2,2,5,3,2,3,6,3,2,4,7,3,2,5,4,5,2,6,3,5,2),
        ncol=6,
        dimnames=list(NULL, c("A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "C"))
    )
  )
```

Below we apply a custom function on each unique column name, `col`:
it selects all the columns named `col` and calculates `rowMeans`. The result, list of atomic vectors, will be coerced to a data.frame:

```
res <- as.data.frame( # sapply returns a list here, so we convert it to a data.frame
    sapply(unique(names(df)), # for each unique column name
       function(col) rowMeans(df[names(df) == col]) # calculate row means
    )
  )
```

The result:

```
res
##     A B   C
## 1 3.0 3 4.5
## 2 3.5 6 4.5
## 3 4.0 3 4.0
## 4 2.0 2 2.0
```

**EDIT:**
As there are many solutions proposed already, let's benchmark them:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, replace=TRUE, 10000*100),
   dimnames=list(NULL, sample(LETTERS[1:5], 100, replace=TRUE)), ncol=100))
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(...)
## Unit: milliseconds
##                   min         lq     median         uq        max neval
## @gagolews   61.196075   65.73211   77.22533  119.42028  127.32557    10
## @joran       8.297964   10.05242   10.90564   15.25943   65.69156    10
## @Davide   5535.272680 5731.24220 5754.67006 5808.47807 5862.22628    10
```

The clear winner (at least as far as speed is concerned) is @joran's `lapply`+`split`+`Reduce`. Congrats! :-)

Comment: Your solution maintains the rownames, whereas joran's drops them (easy enough to re-assign at the end, but the time spent re-assigning them ought to be in the benchmark, for fairness).  (Davide's solution also maintains rownames.)

Answer (score 6):

This works but isn't as nice as gegolews solution, in my opinion:

```
x <- read.table(text = "A B C B A C                             
 1 2 3 4 5 6         
 3 5 6 7 4 3                             
 3 3 3 3 5 5                             
 2 2 2 2 2 2",header = TRUE,sep = "",check.names = FALSE)

as.data.frame(lapply(split(as.list(x),f = colnames(x)),function(x) Reduce(`+`,x) / length(x)))
##    A B   C
##1 3.0 3 4.5
##2 3.5 6 4.5
##3 4.0 3 4.0
##4 2.0 2 2.0
```

Answer (score 6):

Using a combination of `apply` and `tapply`:

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) tapply(x, colnames(df), mean)))

#        A B   C
# [1,] 3.0 3 4.5
# [2,] 3.5 6 4.5
# [3,] 4.0 3 4.0
# [4,] 2.0 2 2.0
```

Comment: Simply clever. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split.default` to divide the dataframe into different groups based in column names and then use `rowMeans` to get the average of columns with same name.

```
sapply(split.default(df, names(df)), rowMeans)
#       A B   C
#[1,] 3.0 3 4.5
#[2,] 3.5 6 4.5
#[3,] 4.0 3 4.0
#[4,] 2.0 2 2.0
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(A = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 2L), B = c(2L, 5L, 3L, 2L), 
    C = c(3L, 6L, 3L, 2L), B = c(4L, 7L, 3L, 2L), A = c(5L, 4L, 
    5L, 2L), C = c(6L, 3L, 5L, 2L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", 
"B", "A", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```