# Computing averages and standard deviations of r data.frames

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` in R and I'd like to compute means and standard deviations. The `data.frame` looks like this:

```
    a    b    c    a   b  c    a   b   c 
id1 1    2    3    4   5  6    7   8   9
id2 9    8    7    6   5  4    3   2   1
```

How can I average/sd the columns?

i.e. For average:

```
    a    b    c
id1 4    5    6     #average of a's b's and c's for ID1
id2 .    .    .
```

Comment: Is it possible to have same column names in a dataframe?

Comment: @Prradep No the IDs are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split.default` to divide the dataframe into different groups based in column names and then carry out necessary operation. To calculate mean for
columns with same name, [use this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46202066/7128934)

For standard deviation, you can use `apply` on each sub-group

```
sapply(split.default(df, names(df)), function(a) apply(a, 1, sd))
#    a b c
#id1 3 3 3
#id2 3 3 3
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(a = c(1L, 9L), b = c(2L, 8L), c = c(3L, 7L), a = c(4L, 
6L), b = c(5L, 5L), c = c(6L, 4L), a = c(7L, 3L), b = c(8L, 2L
), c = c(9L, 1L)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", 
"b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("id1", "id2"))
```