# R calculate standard deviation for the columns with same names

Tags: r, sapply, standard-deviation

I have a quick question

I had a dataframe with many measurements column. I wanted to calculate mean for the columns having same (header)names.. I used the code below (found in stackoverflow)..

[How to calculate the mean of those columns in a data frame with the same column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815727/how-to-calculate-the-mean-of-those-columns-in-a-data-frame-with-the-same-column)

As a example data...

```
df <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3, 4,5),
                 c(2, 3, 4,NA,2),
                 c(3, 4, 5,3,6),
                 c(3, 7, NA,3,6))
names(df) <- c("a", "b", "a", "b")

df <- sapply(split.default(df, names(df)), rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The result is like this...

```
a    b
2    2.5
3    5
4    4
3.5  3
5.5  4
```

This code gave me mean of the columns with same (header)name.

But I want the standard deviation too. I tried replacing rowMeans with rowSds, but it didn't work.

Any idea how to use the same code to calculate standard deviation along with the mean??

Comment: Can you put some reproducible code of your `df`? `data.frame` structure is meant to have unique column names, so your question is missing something, I guess.

Comment: Also, you might want to include packages you are using in your code example, since `rowSds` isn't a base R package and there are a few that have that function.

Comment: What do you mean b columns with same name?

Comment: @SciGuyMcQ I meant the column head names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea basing on your previous approach is to do the following

```
sapply(split.default(df, names(df)), function(x) apply(x, 1, sd, na.rm=TRUE))
#              a         b
# [1,] 1.4142136 0.7071068
# [2,] 1.4142136 2.8284271
# [3,] 1.4142136        NA
# [4,] 0.7071068        NA
# [5,] 0.7071068 2.8284271
```

Keep in mind that `NAs` are returned because `sd` shouldn't be evaluated on a sample of size `1`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3),
                 c(2, 3, 4),
                 c(3, 4, 5))
names(df) <- c("a", "b", "a")


sapply(split.default(df, names(df)), function(smaller_df) {
  sapply(smaller_df, function(col) c(mean(col), sd(col)))
})
```

The first sapply works on each data.frame produced by split, each of which will correspond to a set of columns that have the same name. The second sapply applies to each column.

If you wanted to get the mean and standard deviation for all the measurements in a column with the given name combined, instead of as separate samples, you would change the inner sapply to:

```
sapply(list(unlist(smaller_df)), function(col) c(mean(col), sd(col)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But it didnt give me the desired result. I have used you same df and modified the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a user-defined function which could be useful. You may like to check it out:

[rowVars](https://github.com/cran/Rfast/blob/master/R/rowVars.R)

Comment: Thanks. But i tried this already. It didnt work. It says rowVars object not found.

Comment: It isn't a core function, so it won't be defined unless you run the code that defines it, or import the whole package.