# How to calculate mean and standard deviation in a dataframe/matrix grouped by column name

Tags: r, dataframe, mean, standard-deviation

Example data:

|  | sun | sun | sun | sky | sky |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 1.1 | 4.0 | 9.8 |
| 2 | 3.7 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 3.3 | NA |
| 3 | 1.5 | 0.4 | 2.1 | 3.3 | 6.0 |
| 4 | 3.7 | NA | 3.6 | 3.1 | 5.6 |
| 5 | 2.9 | 1.1 | 10.0 | 7.1 | 7.7 |
| 6 | 7.0 | 4.9 | 6.9 | 5.4 | 4.9 |

I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation (ignoring NAs) of each unique column name to get an output like this:

|  | mean | sd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sun | 3.170588235 | 2.677630647 |
| sky | 5.472727273 | 2.102422845 |

Reproducible data:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1, 3.7, 1.5, 3.7, 2.9, 7),
                 c(2, 1, 0.4, NA, 1.1, 4.9),
                 c(1.1, 1, 2.1, 3.6, 10, 6.9),
                 c(4, 3.3, 3.3, 3.1, 7.1, 5.4),
                 c(9.8, NA, 6, 5.6, 7.7, 4.9))
names(df) <- c("sun", "sun", "sun", "sky", "sky")
```

The closest I've gotten is

```
#for mean
sapply(split.default(df, names(df)), rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE) 

#for sd
sapply(split.default(df, names(df)), function(x) apply(x, 1, sd, na.rm=TRUE))
```

which I got from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284701/r-calculate-standard-deviation-for-the-columns-with-same-names) but I don't know how to tweak it to get what I want. I know that I can take the average of the rowmeans to get mean for each group but this does not work for standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following solution:

```
t(as.data.frame(split.default(df, names(df)) |>
  sapply(\(x) {unlist(data.frame(mean = mean(unlist(x), na.rm = TRUE),
                          sd = sd(unlist(x), na.rm = TRUE)))}))) |> 
  as.data.frame()

        mean       sd
sky 5.472727 2.102423
sun 3.170588 2.677631
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use

```
t(sapply(split.default(df, names(df)), function(x)  {
    x1 <- unlist(x)
    data.frame(mean = mean(x1, na.rm = TRUE), sd = sd(x1, na.rm = TRUE))}))
```

-output

```
       mean     sd      
sky 5.472727 2.102423
sun 3.170588 2.677631
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("^sun", "^sky"), 
  value.name = c("sun", "sky"))[, c(list(categ = c("mean", "sd")), 
    lapply(.SD, function(x) c(mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
     sd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)))), .SDcols = sun:sky]
   categ      sun      sky
1:  mean 3.170588 5.472727
2:    sd 2.677631 2.102423
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a `tidyverse` solution

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(c(1, 3.7, 1.5, 3.7, 2.9, 7),
                 c(2, 1, 0.4, NA, 1.1, 4.9),
                 c(1.1, 1, 2.1, 3.6, 10, 6.9),
                 c(4, 3.3, 3.3, 3.1, 7.1, 5.4),
                 c(9.8, NA, 6, 5.6, 7.7, 4.9))
names(df) <- c("sun", "sun", "sun", "sky", "sky")
```

### Code

```
df %>%
  #Pivotting data
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  #Grouping by sun/sky
  group_by(name) %>% 
  #Caluclating mean and sg grouped by sun/sky
  summarise(
    mean = mean(value,na.rm = T),
    sd = sd(value,na.rm = T)
  )
```

### Output

```
  name   mean    sd
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 sky    5.47  2.10
2 sun    3.17  2.68
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way in `dplyr` bringing values of similar named columns in one column and then calculating `mean` and `sd` on them.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_to = '.value') %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = list(mean = ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                              sd = ~sd(., na.rm = TRUE))))

#  sun_mean sun_sd sky_mean sky_sd
#     <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     3.17   2.68     5.47   2.10
```

If you want `mean` and `sd` values in separate columns you can add to the above answer -

```
 %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c('col', '.value'), names_sep = '_')

#  col    mean    sd
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 sun    3.17  2.68
#2 sky    5.47  2.10
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
df = data.frame(c(1, 3.7, 1.5, 3.7, 2.9, 7),
c(2, 1, 0.4, NA, 1.1, 4.9),
c(1.1, 1, 2.1, 3.6, 10, 6.9),
c(4, 3.3, 3.3, 3.1, 7.1, 5.4),
c(9.8, NA, 6, 5.6, 7.7, 4.9))
names(df) <- c("sun1", "sun2", "sun3", "sky1", "sky2") # it's good to have unique names
```

We need to do a bit of reshaping (to long). As an advocate of base-r, I'd use `stats::reshape`.

However, we need to add one more `sky column` (of **NAs**) to the data.frame so that `reshape` works, but this won't do anything to the computation later since we'll use `na.rm=T`.

```r
df[, 'sky3'] = rep(NA, nrow(df))

df_long = reshape(df, direction = 'long', varying = c(1:3, 4:6), sep="", times=1:3)

df_long 

    time  sun sky  id
1.1    1  1.0 4.0  1
2.1    1  3.7 3.3  2
3.1    1  1.5 3.3  3
4.1    1  3.7 3.1  4
5.1    1  2.9 7.1  5
6.1    1  7.0 5.4  6
1.2    2  2.0 9.8  1
2.2    2  1.0  NA  2
3.2    2  0.4 6.0  3
4.2    2   NA 5.6  4
5.2    2  1.1 7.7  5
6.2    2  4.9 4.9  6
1.3    3  1.1  NA  1
2.3    3  1.0  NA  2
3.3    3  2.1  NA  3
4.3    3  3.6  NA  4
5.3    3 10.0  NA  5
6.3    3  6.9  NA  6
```

```r
lapply(df_long[, c('sun', 'sky')],
 \(x, na.rm=T) list(mean=mean(x, na.rm=na.rm), sd=sd(x, na.rm=na.rm))) |> 
do.call(what = rbind)
    mean     sd      
sun 3.170588 2.677631
sky 5.472727 2.102423
```