# How to average columns with the same name and ignore columns that are factors

Tags: r

I would like to average data from columns with the same name pattern. Some of these examples work great if you only have numeric data:

[How to calculate the mean of those columns in a data frame with the same column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815727/how-to-calculate-the-mean-of-those-columns-in-a-data-frame-with-the-same-column)

However, I also have a column that is a factor. I can remove this column then c(bind) to bring it back but that seems clunky. Is there a way I can use something like    `!is.factor(x)` to ignore my other column?

```
df <- 
as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,3,3,2,2,5,3,2,3,6,3,2,4,7,3,2,5,4,5,2,6,3,5,2),
     ncol=6,
     dimnames=list(NULL, c("A.1", "B.1", "C.1", "B.2", "A.2", "C.2"))))

char = c("Apple", "banana", "cat", "rainbow")
df = cbind(char, df)

res <- as.data.frame(sapply(unique(names(df)), function(col) 
rowMeans(df[names(df) == col] )))
```

The expected results are:
    `res
    char A B C
    Apple 3.0 3 4.5
    banana 3.5 6 4.5
    cat 4.0 3 4.0
    rainbow 2.0 2 2.0`

The error is:

```
` Error in rowMeans(df[names(df) == col]) : 'x' must be numeric `
```

Comment: Your error is due to the `char` column being a `character` vector and not a `numeric` vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a base R solution by extending what you have,

```
df <- 
  as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,3,3,2,2,5,3,2,3,6,3,2,4,7,3,2,5,4,5,2,6,3,5,2),
                       ncol=6,
                       dimnames=list(NULL, c("A.1", "B.1", "C.1", "B.2", "A.2", "C.2"))))

char = c("Apple", "banana", "cat", "rainbow")
df <- cbind(char, df)

names(df) <- gsub('.\\d', '', grep('[a-zA-Z]', names(df), value = TRUE)) ## removes the digit from your groups

res <-
  data.frame(
    factor = df$char,
    sapply(setdiff(unique(names(df)), 'char'), function(col)
      rowMeans(df[, names(df) == col]))
  )

> res
   factor   A B   C
1   Apple 3.0 3 4.5
2  banana 3.5 6 4.5
3     cat 4.0 3 4.0
4 rainbow 2.0 2 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse, I came up with the following pipe operation

```
##Recreate the data
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,3,3,2,2,5,3,2,3,6,3,2,4,7,3,2,5,4,5,2,6,3,5,2),
                   ncol=6,
                   dimnames=list(NULL, c("A.1", "B.1", "C.1", "B.2", "A.2", "C.2"))))

char = c("Apple", "banana", "cat", "rainbow")
df = cbind(char, df)

##Load tidyverse

library(tidyverse)

#Gather the columns with titles, extract the first letter, then summarize
 new_df <- df %>% gather(column_type, value, `A.1`:`C.2`) %>%
           mutate(initial = str_extract(column_type, "[A-Z]")) %>%
           group_by(initial, char) %>% 
           summarise(mean = mean(value)) %>%
           spread(initial, mean)

new_df
```

Answer (score 0):

in base R: you are looking for the following:

```
aggregate(.~char, reshape(df, 2:ncol(df), idvar = 'char',dir = 'long'), mean)[-2]

     char   A B   C
1   Apple 3.0 3 4.5
2  banana 3.5 6 4.5
3     cat 4.0 3 4.0
4 rainbow 2.0 2 2.0

library(datatable)
melt(setDT(df),'char',patterns(A='^A',B='^B',C='^C'))[,-2][,lapply(.SD,mean),by=char]
        char   A B   C
1:   Apple 3.0 3 4.5
2:  banana 3.5 6 4.5
3:     cat 4.0 3 4.0
4: rainbow 2.0 2 2.0
```